# I'm getting the error Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead on swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, type-mismatch

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. The console says I'm declaring code as a String, but it's actually an Int. Any help?

The exact error message I'm getting is this one:

`DEBUG: Something happened and couldn't fetch the data: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "code", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))))`

`DEBUG: There was an error with the API calling: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "code", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))))`

My struct:

```
struct Response: Decodable {

let code: Int?
let status: String?
let copyright: String?
var data: MarvelData?
}
```

**EDIT 1:** The rest of my Structs.

```
struct MarvelData: Decodable {

let count: Int?
var limit: Int?
let offset: Int?
let results: [Characters]?
}

struct Characters: Decodable {

var id: Int?
var name: String?
var description: String?
var thumbnail: Images?
}
```

The JSON Schema is:
[JSON Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knbx7.png)

My API Call is:

```
AF.request(baseURL, parameters: ["apikey": publicKey,
                                     "ts" : ts,
                                     "hash": hash]).responseMarvel { (response) in

        if let error = response.error {
            
            print("DEBUG: Something happened and couldn't fetch the data: \(error)")
            handler(.failure(error))
        }
                                        
        do {
            let marvelFetch = response.value
            let results     = marvelFetch?.data?.results
            
            guard let marvelStuff = results as [Characters]? else { return }
            
            characterArray = marvelStuff

            handler(.success(characterArray))
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: You had an error creating JSON: \(error)")
        }
   }.resume()
```

Comment: How does the failing JSON look like?

Comment: That's on the JSON Schema picture

Comment: It meant that the `code` wasn't an `Int` as it should be. You printed the error, but could you also do in the `catch` print("It failed with responseString "\(String(data: response.data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")")`

Comment: Edit your question and post your actual JSON string returned by the API

Comment: @3rnestocs Guys above mean, can you send us a raw JSON string that you using for `JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: response.data)`. You can do it before you do decoding to the actual model with `print(String(data: response.data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "No reponse")`

Comment: @Larme @Andrew I've solved it, I had my baseUrl as an inexistent endpoint. That's why I was getting a string code response, it said `{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/v1/public/character does not exist"}`

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Error message is clear here. It means that the variable "code" used in the Response struct is declared as an Int but its type in the JSON response is String.